# Why is this CSS3 transition not fired?

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, transition

I have a `<div>` of the class `spoiler` with an additional class `collapsed` which limits its height.
However when I add and remove the `collapsed` class, the CSS3 transition for `height` is not fired.

```
div.spoiler { height: auto; transition: height 2s ease; }
div.spoiler.collapsed { height: 4px; overflow: hidden; }
```

I have found this online resource which does the same thing using jQuery (I'm using Dojo), which works: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-transitions-javascript/

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/2Cnxv/

How do I get my transition to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered somewhere else.

You can not transition height from a numeric value to auto (or the other way round).

One workaround that is to transition the max-height, setting it high enough (the problem is that you have to guess that number)

```
div.foo { height: auto; 
    max-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid red; 
    transition: max-height 2s ease; }
div.foo.bar { 
    max-height: 4px; 
    overflow: hidden; }
```